# Twitter Cards not expanded by default

Tags: twitter, meta, rdfa, twitter-card

I am trying to create Twitter cards using the twitter meta tags (and Open Graph for other sites like Facebook). When I see my twitter feed from others like say NPR News the cards are expanded by default.

However when I post the same content - the card is not expanded by default. I have to click on the tweet and the click on "Details" or "View Summary" which redirects me to a new page where the card is expanded.

What makes twitter decide weather to display the card (in my case Summary Large) expanded or collapsed?

**Edit:**

Here are the meta tags in use,

```
<meta property="og:title" content="**masked**"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="**masked**" />
<meta property="og:image" content="**masked**" />   
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta property="twitter:image:src" content="**masked**" />
<meta property='twitter:site' content='**masked**'/>
```

(I am currently not using twitter:title and twitter:description since those are being read by twitter from the OpenGraph equivalent tags used.)

Comment: Note I have looked at the link https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-come-some-twitter-cards-are-already-partly-expanded-how-can-i-make-my-cards-do-this/16200 and I didn't find it helpful.

Comment: Can you post what meta tags you are using in your website? Was it validated correctly?

Comment: @aug, added the details you requested. However I would like to stress that a link that shows expanded by say a certain news site - if I shared the same link directly it would be collapsed (unless I retweet).

Comment: I think this is the expected behavior (sadly). Take a look at this [discussion](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-cards-validated-and-preview-ok-but-photos-not-are-pre-expanded/25702/2). Specifically it will only show by default if its a promoted tweet or the image is hosted by Twitter.

Comment: Thanks and voted up @aug! This is really disappointing, but I will look at the other option of images uploaded natively on twitter. Thanks.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer since it seems it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this [discussion](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-cards-validated-and-preview-ok-but-photos-not-are-pre-expanded/25702/2). This is the expected behavior of Twitter cards (sadly).

If you want to show it by default, the tweet has to be either [promoted](https://business.twitter.com/solutions/promoted-tweets?lang=en&location=na) or the image has to be hosted on Twitter's site (if it's hosted on a third party website, it will not show by default).

Comment: "or the image has to be hosted on Twitter's site" Does this still work? Perhaps I misunderstand? One would do this... 1. post a tweet that uploads a picture 2. get the link to the picture such as https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CVULb82XAAAMkZ3.png 3. use that link for `twitter:image:src`. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Twitter is now auto-expanding cards in their android and ios apps. Still not on desktop and mobile web though.

Answer (score 0):

aug wrote

> If you want to show it by default, the tweet has to be either promoted or the image has to be hosted on Twitter's site

but that's not true. I have had cards that were expanded by default. They were standard [Summary Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary), though, and not [Summary Cards with Large Image](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image). Maybe that's where Twitter makes a difference? The reasoning could be that the small image shown in a standard Summary Card takes less bandwidth and attention. This is speculative. Can anybody confirm?